# Adding a claim using a custom endpoint with AddLocalApiAuthentication

Tags: identityserver4

I'm attempting to employ a custom endpoint that adds a specific claim based on a parameter passed to LocalApiController.

I'm following help at:

```
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html
```

I configured `startup.cs`:

```
    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication(principal =>
    {
        principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("additional_claim", "additional_value"));

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    });
```

and my receiving `controller`:

```
    [Route("localApi")]
    [Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
    public class LocalApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var claims = from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value };
            return new JsonResult(claims);
        }
    }
```

`[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]` works and fires the helper configured in `startup.cs` which logically fires before the controllers `get` method.

I don't see how I can pass the controller's `{id}` parameter to the helper method (that will become the value of the claim I'm to add, replacing the `"additional_value"` constant).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds a lot like how [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) works. Take a look at the _Free, Open Source PolicyServer_, and in particular the [code](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/PolicyServer.Local/AspNetCore/PolicyServerMiddleware.cs) where the claims are added. The local version gets the claims from the [json config](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/Host/Startup.cs#L33), but you can replace that with a call to an endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Ruard, not "seeing" it...  How about this: can you explain why the example uses: .AddClaim(new Claim("additional_claim", "additional_value")), adding a constant here makes no sense to me, adding a variable does.  All the examples are so complete it makes me think I'm missing something...

Comment: Why do you need claims transformation? This is not about adding new claims but about applying rules. E.g. when external authorities (like google, microsoft, etc.) use different claim types. Or a claim has to be determined from other claims / information. So when you want to add claims, then claims transformation may not what you are looking for. Perhaps you should extend your configuration, extend the ProfileService or use an external (or local) source, like the PolicyServer, that actually adds claims and dynamic policies from another source (json config or any source you configure).

Comment: Ahha, wrong tool for the job...  What I was aiming for was adding a claim after a user has been authenticated and I subsequently learned something about that person prompting me to return to STS to add a claim and have it included in the token...

Comment: Why not just add the claim to the response from the controller?